# how to fix the error in python code?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    fname = input("Enter name of file: ")
    with open(fname) as inf:
        animalnames, dates, locations = zip(*[line.strip().split(':') for line in inf])

    d = {}
    for animalname, loc in zip(animalname, locations):
        d.setdefault(animalname, []).append(loc)  

    for k, v in d.items():
       print(k, end='\t')
       print(v.count('loc1'), end='\t')
       print(v.count('loc2'))        

main()
```

i have a txt file name animallog1.txt which contains the following

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1 
a03:01-24-2011:s2 
a02:01-24-2011:s2 
a03:02-02-2011:s2 
a03:03-02-2011:s1 
a02:04-19-2011:s2 
a01:05-14-2011:s2 
a02:06-11-2011:s2 
a03:07-12-2011:s1 
a01:08-19-2011:s1 
a03:09-19-2011:s1 
a03:10-19-2011:s2 
a03:11-19-2011:s1 
a03:12-19-2011:s2
```

i would like to use the above data which is in the format animaname:data:location to print the following table:

```
Number of times each animal visited each station : 
Animal name Station 1 Station 2 
a01         2         1 
a02         0         3 
a03         4         4 
========================================
```

i have tried and my code is what i have got, but it gives me the error

```
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'animalname' referenced before assignment
```

could someone help me fix this so i can get the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to refer `animalnames` here

```
for animalname, loc in zip(animalnames, locations):
```

Comment: i have another problem now, the table is not showing the right data, as it should contains numbers and not zeros....

Answer (score 0):

In response to your second question, are you searching for the exact string names of the stations with count?

I see "loc1" and "loc2" are hard-coded into the provided snippet, and am wondering if that is just by way of example, or if the final script uses those instead of "s1" and "s2" or some flexible parameters.

Comment: i am pretty sure that i am not

Comment: Can you post the snippet that is returning 0 where you expect other numbers, and a short piece of a file you're parsing?